# Haskell read function with no annotation

Tags: haskell

Does haskell read function implicitly converts a data type into another?

```
import IO

main = do
    putStrLn "Enter an interger: "
    num <- getLine
    putStr "Value + 3 is "
    putStrLn (show((read num) + 3))
```

So, haskell interpreter automatically changes num's data type from string to int to handle '+ 3'?

Comment: `IO` is not a standard module that you can import, and your code works without any imports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`read` has type `Read a => String -> a`, which means that it can convert a `String` into any type that is an instance of the `Read` type class. Which type it will use depends on the surrounding code. In this case you write `read num + 3`. The `+` operator is also overloaded to work for any type that is an instance of `Num`, so the type of `read num + 3` is `(Read a, Num a) => a`. Haskell has a mechanism that chooses a default type whenever the `Num` type class remains in the final type of an expression. In this case it defaults to `Integer`, so the final type is `Integer`.

You can see this in action by enabling the `-Wtype-defaults` warning which is also included in `-Wall`:

```
Test.hs:5:15: warning: [-Wtype-defaults]
    • Defaulting the following constraints to type ‘Integer’
        (Show a0) arising from a use of ‘show’ at Test.hs:5:15-34
        (Num a0) arising from a use of ‘+’ at Test.hs:5:20-33
        (Read a0) arising from a use of ‘read’ at Test.hs:5:21-28
    • In the first argument of ‘putStrLn’, namely
        ‘(show ((read num) + 3))’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: putStrLn (show ((read num) + 3))
      In the expression:
        do putStrLn "Enter an interger: "
           num <- getLine
           putStr "Value + 3 is "
           putStrLn (show ((read num) + 3))
  |
5 |     putStrLn (show((read num) + 3))
  |
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you are using

```
show :: Show a => a -> String
read :: Read a => String -> a
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
3 :: Num a => a
```

on the same type `a`. So, Haskell searches for a type `a` satisfying `Show a, Read a, Num a`.

In principle, this would be rejected since the type is ambiguous, but Haskell mandates a special rules for `Num`, causing `a` to be defaulted, usually to `Integer`. Since that satisfies also `Show` and `Read`, the program type-checks.